# Сделать из одного массива другой с изменением ключей Object.entries

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть изначальный массив вида:

```
[
   {
      "id":1287,
      "name":"name1",
      "params":[
         {
            "param1":"10",
            "type":"UInt32"
         },
         {
            "param2":"30",
            "type":"UInt16"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":1288,
      "name":"name2 ",
      "params":[
         {
            "param3":"20",
            "type":"Date"
         },
         {
            "param4":"34",
            "type":"String"
         },
         {
            "param5":"15",
            "type":"UInt8"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Его надо перевести в массив вида:

```
[
   {
      "id":1287,
      "name":"name1",
      "params":[
         {
            "name":"name1",
            "key":"param1",
            "value":"10",
            "type":"UInt32"
         },
         {
            "name":"name1",
            "key":"param2",
            "value":"30",
            "type":"UInt32"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":1288,
      "name":"name2",
      "params":[
         {
            "name":"name2",
            "key":"param3",
            "value":"20",
            "type":"UInt32"
         },
         {
            "name":"name2",
            "key":"param4",
            "value":"34",
            "type":"UInt32"
         },
         {
            "name":"name2",
            "key":"param5",
            "value":"15",
            "type":"UInt32"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Была попытка для переведения "param1": 10 в "key":"param1","value":"10" использовать map и Object.entries, но не получается привести все к нужному виду и добавить в новые объекты внутри params внешний name.

Подскажите, какое решение тут было бы лучше?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var a = [ { "id":1287, "name":"name1", "params":[ { "param1":"10", "type":"UInt32" }, { "param2":"30", "type":"UInt16" } ] }, { "id":1288, "name":"name2 ", "params":[ { "param3":"20", "type":"Date" }, { "param4":"34", "type":"String" }, { "param5":"15", "type":"UInt8" } ] } ]

console.log(a.map(x => ({
  ...x,
  params: x.params.map(p => {
    var keys = Object.keys(p).filter(k => k !== 'type')
    if (keys.length !== 1) throw new Error("Invalid number of keys")
  
    return {
      name: x.name,
      key: keys[0],
      value: p[keys[0]],
      type: p.type,
    }
  }),
})))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Comment: Там, кажется, нужно все типы унифицировать.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty, не понял.

Comment: Ну, судя по примеру результата, во всех элементах должно быть `"type":"UInt32"`, но это легко добавить в решение.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty, я даже внимания не обратил. Подозреваю, что он криво накопипастил когда задавал вопрос.

Comment: Может быть. Ну, не существенно)

Answer (score 1):

Если можно менять исходную структуру:

```js
const data = [
   {
      "id":1287,
      "name":"name1",
      "params":[
         {
            "param1":"10",
            "type":"UInt32"
         },
         {
            "param2":"30",
            "type":"UInt16"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":1288,
      "name":"name2 ",
      "params":[
         {
            "param3":"20",
            "type":"Date"
         },
         {
            "param4":"34",
            "type":"String"
         },
         {
            "param5":"15",
            "type":"UInt8"
         }
      ]
   }
];

for (const item of data) {
  item.params.forEach((param, i, params) => {
    const [key, value] = Object.entries(param).find(
      ([k]) => k.startsWith('param')
    );
    params[i] = {
      name: item.name,
      key: key,
      value: value,
      type: 'UInt32',
    };
  });
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, '  '));
```